# python slicing a list by 200 and deal with leftovers

Tags: python, list

let's assume that there is a list named 'user_ids' as below

```
>>> len(user_ids)
>>> 742
```

I want to slice the list by 200
after 742/200 -> 3 times of loop, there going to be a 142 stuffs left
with the result, I want it to be in a list again.
the result would have the same value with below

```
sliced_list = [user_ids[0:199],user_ids[200:399],user_ids[400:599],user_uds[600:742]]
```

I want to make a loop to deal with the user_ids list no matter how many stuffs it has.

I cannot figure out where to start.....any ideas?

Comment: Replace `user_ids[600:742]` by `user_ids[600:]`

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it will work with any length of user_ids

```
sliced_list = []
for u in range(0, len(user_ids), 200):
    sliced_list.append(user_ids[u: u + 200])
```

or with a list comprehension

```
[user_ids[u: u + 200] for u in range(0, len(user_ids), 200)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work but I'm sure there is a prettier way

```
tempList = []
for i in range(len(user_ids):
    if i % 200 == 0:
        newList.append(tempList)
        tempList = []
    tempList.append(user_ids[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
print([l[200*i:200*(i+1)] for i in range(len(user_ids) // 200)])
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the range function along with the step value for a clean one liner.

```
sliced_ids = [user_ids[i:i+200] for i in range(0, len(user_ids), 200)]
```

If one liner is ugly to the eye, following for loop will do the trick:

```
sliced_ids = []
slice_length = 200
for i in range(0, len(user_ids), slice_length):
    sliced_ids.append(user_ids[i:i+slice_length])
```

I prefer the one liner over the second. But not going to judge if one going to use the second approach.